# Distribution and other rules for floor and ceiling

Tags: functions

I've been working on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) and have found myself using the floor and ceiling functions a lot. I was hoping somebody could help me figure out how distribution and other properties of these functions work.

1. Is `floor(x) + floor(y) = floor(x+y)` ?
2. Is `floor(x) = y` the same as `x = ceil(y)` and vice-versa?

Remember, I'm asking about all real numbers, not just integers.
Are there any other rules about floor/ceil I should know about?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a nice long list of formulas and identities: http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Floor/

Answer (score 6):

I managed to find a list of properties of `ceil` and `floor` functions in this blog: https://janmr.com/blog/2009/09/useful-properties-of-the-floor-and-ceil-functions/ It contains various relations between these functions, their results and argument values. It also contain some references for further reading.

Please find below some of these properties for real numbers.

#### (In)equalities

$$
x - 1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x \leq \lceil x \rceil < x + 1
$$
$$
\lfloor -x \rfloor = -\lceil x \rceil
$$
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor + k = \lfloor x + k \rfloor
$$
$$
\lceil x \rceil + k = \lceil x + k \rceil
$$

$$
\Bigl\lfloor \frac{n}{m}\Bigr\rfloor = \Bigl\lceil \frac{n - m + 1}{m} \Bigr\rceil
$$

$$
\Bigl\lceil \frac{n}{m}\Bigr\rceil = \Bigl\lfloor \frac{n + m - 1}{m} \Bigr\rfloor
$$

#### Increasing functions

If a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and monotonically increasing and for each integer $f(x)$ the value of $x$ is also an integer (e.g. $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$), we have:

$$
\lfloor f( \lfloor x \rfloor ) \rfloor = \lfloor f(x) \rfloor
$$

$$
\lceil f( \lceil x \rceil ) \rceil = \lceil f(x) \rceil
$$

#### Logarithms

For integer $k$ and all $b > 0$, $b \neq 1$:

$$
k =\lfloor \log_b{x} \rfloor \Leftrightarrow b^k \leq x < b^{k + 1}
$$

$$
k = \lceil \log_b{x} \rceil \Leftrightarrow b^{k - 1} < x \leq b^k
$$

#### References

The references are taken from the blog above:

- "Concrete Mathematics" by *R. L. Graham, D. E. Knuth, and O. Patashnik*
- "The Art of Computer Programming", Volume 1, *by Donald E. Knuth*.

Comment: Could you summarize some of these properties? (The webpage may not be around forever)

Comment: @air-conditioner, I've updated my answer, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Your statements are both false. Here are counter-examples:

For $x=y=.5$, $\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor=0$, but $\lfloor x+y \rfloor=1$.

For $x = .5$, $y=0$, we have $\lfloor x \rfloor =0$ but $\lceil y \rceil = 0 \neq .5$.

It is true that $\lfloor x +y \rfloor - 1 \leq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor \leq \lfloor x+y \rfloor$, because, writing $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \alpha$, $y = \lfloor y \rfloor + \beta$, we have $0 \leq \alpha,\beta < 1$, and $x + y =  \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + \alpha + \beta$. Then:
$$
\lfloor x + y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + \lfloor \alpha + \beta \rfloor,
$$
and $\lfloor \alpha+\beta \rfloor$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed identities aren't true (already explained in another answer),
but this identity is true:

$$\lfloor x \rfloor = -\lceil -x \rceil.$$